# Misdirection spell and Spellcraft

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

I am running a scenario in which the text states that character X will use misdirection to mask her alignment. My question is, misdirection has V and S components and so will not this be obvious and also detectable via spellcraft check to identify spellcasting?

Its kinda pointless to try to hide an NPCs intention if they make an action in defense of your alignment check.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 7):

[Misdirection](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/misdirection) has a duration in hours/level. Presumably they are in the habit of casting it before heading out for the day, with maybe a refresher in the early afternoon.

It's like an adventure that says someone uses a disguise to hide their identity. They're not going to be walking around undisguised, wait until they run into someone, and then be all "oh no! better put on my disguise" and do it in front of them. They'll be using it all the time, and letting the disguise/Misdirection lapse when they're in the privacy of their own space.

Comment: Hah sorry I did not notice the duration bit :) Thanks!